# Enable Disable Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to enable and disable bluetooth in android programmatically..Please help me how to do this..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read the Android documentation to find the answer yourself:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been answered but just in case someone else wants this info.  There are two ways to enable bluetooth one is to use the Intents and send a user request

```
Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
activity.startActivityForResult(enableIntent, someIntegerValue);
```

second is to just call the enable method on the adapter, only use this method if user input is not needed or wanted.

```
BluetoothAdapter blue = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (!blue.isEnabled())
    blue.enable();
```

to disable you just call disable method on adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly open Bluetooth by calling function `turnOn()` on click of button(on):

```
void turnOn()
{
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        status.setText("BlueTooth adapter not found");
    }
    else if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth is already on.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Bluetooth enable

Intent blintent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivity(blintent);

for Bluetooth disable
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();